# FFmpeg error with multiple outputs

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a stream using a webcam as data input with FFmpeg, but I need to stream a video in addition to the stream. Both features with the same command for a few minutes.

(If placed separately the recording code works perfectly)

**FFmpeg code:**

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -t 300 -c:v libx264 -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_format mp4 '/meu_video.mp4' | -s 640x360 -ac 2 -f flv -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 600000 -bufsize 600000 -r 25 -ar 44100 -c:a libfaac -b:a 128k "http://localhost:3030"
```

There are two errors, one when I try to join the two codes using | or \ and the other when I put only the stream code to test.

**Log multiple outputs:**

```
    ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib

libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100

Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Integrated Webcam':
  Duration: N/A, start: 
264374.193000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc

http://localhost:3030/: Unknown error
```

**Edit 3:** I ran the command using -report and generated the report, but it's too big to paste into the question.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xsuzq5fx464o4w/ffmpeg-20171109-145406.log?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separator.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 32M -i video="Integrated Webcam" -t 300 -c:v libx264 -segment_atclocktime 1
       -segment_format mp4 '/meu_video_%d.mp4' -s 640x360 -f flv
       -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 600000 -bufsize 600000 -r 25 "http://localhost:3030"
```

(I haven't removed the audio options although you don't have any audio inputs).

Comment: I don't need audio.

Comment: Your answer solved the error of multiple outputs, but I got a new error about the stream. Can you help me? I updated the question.

Comment: The report is too big to paste into the question. I put it in the dropbox.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6i4h70fvlgt1dt/ffmpeg-20171109-141130.log?dl=0

Comment: Excuse me. Updated log and report.

Comment: Part of the error disappeared with 512M. But it still does not work. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xsuzq5fx464o4w/ffmpeg-20171109-145406.log?dl=0

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, I'll do tests on the server then.